# Where clause not filtering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my model I have the following two functions:

```php
public function Children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Menu::class, 'parent_menu_id', 'id');
}

public function ActiveChildren()
{
    $securityLevel = Auth()->User()->security_level_id;
    $activeChildren = Menu::Children()
        ->where('active_', TRUE)
        ->where('security_level_id', $securityLevel);

    return $activeChildren;
}
```

`Children()` returns a list of all Menu items where their parent_menu_id matches the id of this record. This is used in Nova for setup purposes.

With `ActiveChildren()` I am trying to create a filtered list of items for the actual menu where `active_` = TRUE and `security_level_id` = security level id of the current user.

But instead, `ActiveChildren()` returns all menu items instead of the filtered set. ActiveChildren populates an array in the following static function:

```php
public static function Tree()
{
    return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 4, 'ActiveChildren')))
        ->where('menu_type', '=', 'PRT')
        ->get();
}
```

That is then loaded via the AppServiceProvider whenever the menu is included in a blade file:

```php
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('desktop.menu.parent', function ($view) {
        $items = Menu::Tree();
        $view->withItems($items);
    });
}
```

All this works fine, just the menu items are not filtered, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation, I have found the issue to be in my blade code.

I still referenced `$item['children']` instead of `$item['activechildren']`

```
<li>{{ $item['menu_text'] }}</li>
@if (count($item['activechildren']) > 0)
    <ul>
    @foreach($item['activechildren'] as $item)
        @include('desktop.menu.children', $item)
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Why did `$item['children']` still work? Why wasn't this throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to update your `ActiveChildren()` relation:

```
public function ActiveChildren()
{
    $securityLevel = Auth()->User()->security_level_id;

    /* $activeChildren = Menu::Children()
     *     ->where('active_', TRUE)
     *     ->where('security_level_id', $securityLevel);
     *
     * return $activeChildren;
     */
    return $this->Children() // switch Menu::Children() to $this->Children()
        ->where('active_', TRUE)
        ->where('security_level_id', $securityLevel);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you changed, and why it made a difference? This will make the answer more valuable to both OP and future visitors. (BTW using [the `auth()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-auth) is is a perfectly valid way to get the auth object without having to declare `use /Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth` or whatever. But your change to the second line was definitely needed.)

Comment: @miken32 Thanks for the tip on the auth() helper ... it was the upper case function/method names that were looking wrong to me, but apparently that is valid in PHP.

Comment: Agreed. It took me a while to see the change here.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the help, this solved my issue. I have also corrected my usage of upper case in function names. Still learning laravel/php

Comment: @Peter, actually upon further review, I got confused with my test data. This does not appear to be working. Menu items marked as inactive are still showing up even when using $this

Comment: @C.Gill Can you post your view code as well? I don't see an issue with the boot() or model, but maybe the view has the issue? Or could you do a `dd($items)` in your boot() method to show what you're getting back from your query?

Comment: @Peter, your assumption was correct, see my post below. The issue was in my view, I was referencing $item['children'] instead of $item['activechildren']. Not sure why $item['children'] worked though?

Comment: @C.Gill Laravel Models have some getters that will load the relation if it exists on the Model, even if it isn't loaded yet. So if doesn't behave like an array where you would get an undefined index error when accessing a key that hadn't been set ... even though you are using array style accessors like $model['property'] to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
\App\model_name::where('active_',TRUE)->where('security_level_id', $securityLevel);
```

Comment: As this looks nearly the same as the query given in `ActiveChildren`, can you explain why this one might solve the problem? What was wrong with the original query?